# Can I build a small basement under wood cabin and add an electrical boiler 30L for shower and sink?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, boiler, heater

Can I build a small basement under wood cabin and add an electrical boiler 30L (e.g. Ariston Andris) for shower and sink that would be at ground floor?

Comment: You can, but need to remember you might be disturbing the cabin's supports and cause movement, some you might not like.  Depending how cabin is built and supported, might want expert advice, compared to just digging a hole.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can (broad question, broad answer.)

The details of "how to do that without causing major structural problems or collapse" are variable and site-specific, having a lot to do with how the cabin is presently supported, and how you prevent compromising that support when digging under it.